# Custom iojs addon failed to load RSA private key

Tags: c++, node.js, openssl, io.js

The code snippet that I try to load an RSA private key in iojs addon.

```
void IojsAddon::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  if (args.IsConstructCall()) {
    EVP_PKEY* ca_key;
    BIO* keyb = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    BIO_read_filename(keyb, "/path/to/key.pem");
    ca_key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(keyb, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    std::cout << "type: " << ca_key->type << std::endl; // type: 6
    std::cout << "check: " << RSA_check_key(ca_key->pkey.rsa) << std::endl; // check: -1
    RSA_print_fp(stdout, ca_key->pkey.rsa, 0);  // Segmentation fault: 11

    IojsAddon* addon = new IojsAddon();
    addon->Wrap(args.This());
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(args.This());
  } else {
    const int argc = 1;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = { args[0] };
    Local<Function> cons = Local<Function>::New(isolate, constructor);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(cons->NewInstance(argc, argv));
  }
}
```

The code snippet that load an RSA private key successfully in a standalone application which exactly the same as the previous.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  EVP_PKEY* ca_key;
  BIO* keyb = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  BIO_read_filename(keyb, "/path/to/key.pem");
  ca_key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(keyb, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

  std::cout << "type: " << ca_key->type << std::endl;  // type: 6
  std::cout << "check: " << RSA_check_key(ca_key->pkey.rsa) << std::endl; // check: -1 
  RSA_print_fp(stdout, ca_key->pkey.rsa, 0);  // print out the key info successfully.
  return (0);
}
```

P.S.

- iojs: v1.2.0
- pangyp: v2.0.1

What did I miss here? Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here. Solve it by include openssl header files in `binding.gyp`. I have successfully read an X509 certificate without including any header files for that I just assume the build system will do that for me. But that's not the case. You have to do that on your own.

Check out [Linking-to-OpenSSl](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Linking-to-OpenSSL) for more info about working iojs addon with openssl.